# About Taylor Series and Polynomial functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Suppose we have a Taylor series $F(x) \in R[[x]]$ and suppose for $f(x) \in R[x]$

If $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ are equal (for the interval on which $F(x)$ is defined) for countably infinite many points.

Does $F[x] = f(x)$ on this interval for all points or not?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Note that a polynomial is its own Taylor series.

Comment: Take $F(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f(x)=0$. They agree at $k\pi$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$.